# Check if images have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm loading 8 images with a common class name. E.g.

```
<img class="commonClass" src="..." alt="" />
<img class="commonClass" src="..." alt="" />
<img class="commonClass" src="..." alt="" />
```

How do I use jQuery to know if all 8 images have complete loading?

I tried the below, but was not successful.

```
$('img.commonClass').on('load',function(){
    console.log("loaded");
});
```

Comment: If you know the count, you could count the number of `load` events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var images = $('img.commonClass'),
    loaded = 0,
    target = images.length;

images.on('load',function(){
    loaded++;
    if (loaded == target) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try window onload:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
    console.log("loaded");
});
```

It will also trace whether all the image, frames, etc have been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to your loaded images, comparing the images with that class with the total number of images:

```
$images = $('img.commonClass').on('load', function(){
    $(this).addClass('i_has_loaded');

    var check = $images.length == $images.filter('.i_has_loaded').length;
    if(check){
        alert('All images loaded');
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwhrheyc/1/)

Comment: @Bekki Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add uniq id for each picture.
And call this function for each id picture.

```
$('#any_image_id')
    .load(function(){
        $('#result1').text('Image is loaded!'); 
    })
    .error(function(){
        $('#result1').text('Image is not loaded!');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

to be a little more dynamic:

```js
var loaded = 0, $images = $('img.commonClass');
$images.on('load',function(){
    loaded++;
    if (loaded == $images.length) {
        doSomething();
    }
});
```